# Rails 4 custom validator clarifiaction

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

Im going through custom validations in the rails guides (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations) and im having trouble understanding whats going here. How is the EmailValidator being used? Where is it being called?

```
class EmailValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    unless value =~ /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i
      record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "is not an email")
    end
  end
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :email, presence: true, email: true
end
```

Like where does all the code go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you execute `validates` method passing a hash. When hash is passed, this method iterates over it and for each key it instantiates validator which name matches given key. So if you pass `presence: true`, it instantiate new instance of `PresenceValidator`, similarly `confirmation: true` instantiates `ConfirmationValidator`. If instead of `true`, value is a hash, it is being passed to validator and stored there in instance variable `@options`, which is accessed by `options` reader.

Comment: where do i place the EmailValidator code? and where did you get that description from? i'd like to read more on it..

Comment: @Mulaiko - The beauty of rails is that you can actually read its code rather than documentation. Here you can read both: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates (Note there is small `Source: hide | GitHub` bit at the end.

Comment: @Mulaiko - In regards where to put your validators - You need to put them in any folder which is on your autoload path. I personally place them in lib/validators (which I have to add to autoload path in application.rb), some people prefers to place them in app/validators.

Comment: Thanks for the response. if you can some time can you help me out with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22948051/validating-uniqueness-of-nested-data-using-cancan-gem